# Laravel cashier error

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use laravel cashier for a website I'm building but I am getting this error:

> Declaration of `Laravel\Cashier\BillableTrait::invoices($parameters = Array)` must be compatible with `Laravel\Cashier\BillableInterface::invoices()`

I've followed the installation instructions that are on the laravel website.

My user model:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableTrait;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Laravel\Cashier\BillableTrait;
use Laravel\Cashier\BillableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface, BillableInterface 
{
    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait, BillableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * @var array
     */

    protected $dates = ['trial_ends_at', 'subscription_ends_at'];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you end up resolving this issue? I'm running into it as well.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this error too. It seems to only be a problem (so far) with laravel/cashier version 2.0.4. I reverted to version 2.0.3.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have some composer issues with versions/cache. Have you done a `composer dumpautoload` or better yet a `composer update`, then `php artisan cache:clear`?

What does your `composer.json` look like for the Cashier entry?