# Laravel Cashier BillableInterface Error

Tags: php, laravel

I get the following error after adding the implements BillableInterface line to my User model:

```
    Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_COMPILE_ERROR) 
    Declaration of Laravel\Cashier\BillableTrait::invoices($parameters = Array) must be compatible     
    with Laravel\Cashier\BillableInterface::invoices()
```

I followed the documentation and have since run composer update and then cleared the cache afterwards but still no luck.

Here is the model code:

```
use Laravel\Cashier\BillableTrait;
use Laravel\Cashier\BillableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements BillableInterface  {

use BillableTrait;

/**
 * The database table used by the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'users';

/**
 * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


protected $fillable = array('username','name','email','password');

protected $guarded = array('id');

protected $dates = ['trial_ends_at', 'subscription_ends_at'];
```

Comment: Does the invoices() method signature you created in the interface match your implementation of it?

Comment: I'm not too sure what that means

Comment: This is a duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25234406/laravel-cashier-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually something wrong with PHP 5.4.12. I updated to 5.5.12 and everything is cool.